Binary logistic regression with moderation
I am completing my data analysis for my dissertation. I am testing the likelihood of studying an environmental science degree based on your value type and include climate anxiety level as a moderator.
DV = dichotomous category (Psychology degree or Environmental science degree)
all independent variables are continuous variables (measured with likert scales).
IV1 = Biospheric values
IV2 = Altruistic values
IV3 = Egoistic values
IV4 = Hedonic values
IV5 = Climate anxiety
IV6 = moderation interaction (Climate anxiety*Biospheric values)
I have conducted the binary logistic regression in SPSS. I was wondering what is the best way to illustrate these results for my results section i.e. simple slope analysis, etc.?
Any advice is appreciated!

First, strictly speaking, Likert scales are not continuous, although they often get treated that way. I added the "Likert" and "Ordinal" tags. You can look at those and see arguments for treating them as ordinal (which is, strictly, correct) or continuous.
Second for illustrating your results, for the three variables that are not involved in interactions, you can make graphs of the probability of one of the two results (on the Y axis) and the independent variable on the X-axis. You can probably put all three of those on one graph.
For the variables involved in an interaction, I would put one of them on the x-axis and then have 5 lines (one for each level of the other independent variable).
